# How to avoid duplicate TestFixtures arrangements for every test?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, xunit.net, autofixture

I have a number of tests that all arrange some TestFixtures and I'm finding that I'm duplicating that arrangement code a *lot*. The first few lines of every test are nearly identical.

Is there a way to declare one shared TestFixture across all tests while still "resetting" them between each test, therefore maintaining test independence?

```
public class MyClassTests
{
    private readonly Mock<ICoolService> _mockCoolService;
    private readonly Mock<IGreatService> _mockGreatService;
    private readonly Mock<INiceService> _mockNiceService;
    private readonly MyClass _controller;

    public MyClassTests(){

        //initialize the services.

        _controller = new MyClass(_mockCoolService.Object, _mockGreatService.Object, _mockNiceService.Object);
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task MyTest_ShouldDoThis(){
        var batchName = TestFixture.Create<string>();
        var documentName = TestFixture.Create<string>();
        var controlId = TestFixture.Create<int>();

        _mockCoolService.Setup(x=>x.ACoolMethod(batchName, documentName)).Returns(batchName)

        var result = _controller.DoThis()

        //VerifyAll
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task MyTest_ShouldDoThat(){
        var batchName = TestFixture.Create<string>();
        var documentName = TestFixture.Create<string>();
        var controlId = TestFixture.Create<int>();

        _mockGreatService.Setup(x=>x.AGreatMethod(batchName, documentName)).Returns(batchName)

        var result = _controller.DoThat()

        //VerifyAll
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task MyTest_ShouldDoAnotherThing(){
        var batchName = TestFixture.Create<string>();
        var documentName = TestFixture.Create<string>();
        var controlId = TestFixture.Create<int>();

        _mockNiceService.Setup(x=>x.ANiceMethod(batchName, documentName)).Returns(batchName)

        var result = _controller.DoAnotherThing()

        //VerifyAll
    }
}
```

Comment: Put them in the constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The xUnit documentation suggests putting code like this in the constructor:

> xUnit.net creates a new instance of the test class for every test that
>   is run, so any code which is placed into the constructor of the test
>   class will be run for every single test.

[xUnit documentation: Shared context between tests](https://xunit.net/docs/shared-context)